# Elements with same Ids - toggle class?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using a for loop to iterate through a list of items that create a collapsable container... the problem is I need to toggle the icon from an up arrow to a down arrow but the id's are all the same and it will only work on the first container. Is there a way to do this? here's my code:

**cshtml**

```
@foreach (var category in ViewBag.Checklists)
        {

            <div class="searchPanel">
                <div class="card" style="background-color: #efefef; margin-bottom:  20px;">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="row search-row d-flex">
                            <div class="mr-auto">
                                <label> @category.Name</label>
                            </div>
                            @{ var boxId = "test" + category.Id; }
                            <div id="#searchContainer">
                                <a id="showHide" href="#@boxId" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" class="fa fa-a4 toggleSearchFields fa-chevron-down" title=" "></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="@boxId" class="ml-3 card-body collapse">
                        <div class="threerow-grid-container">
                            """"content goes here"""
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

and the **Jquery** I tried:

```
$("#showHide").click(function () {
$(".toggleSearchFields").closest("a").toggleClass("fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down");
});
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you should use a class.

Comment: How, I dont see how this will resolve my issue? It will apply it to all the containers with the same name class.

Comment: this solved my issue:
$(document).on("click", function (event) {
    $(event.target).closest("a").toggleClass("fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down");
});

Comment: I usually use `$(this)`